# How to center & scale map in d3js (use projection.center/translate/rotate?)

Tags: d3.js, maps, visualization, map-projections

Given that I have topoJSON data of a given geographical feature and a specific projection.

How should I center and scale the map to fit its parent object?

It seems I can use either projection.rotate(), projection.translate() or projection.center() to center a map:

https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Geo-Projections.md

What are the differences and how does scale affect the different functions?

Answer (score 5):

Use `projection.fitExtent()` in v4. [Documentation](https://github.com/d3/d3-geo#projection_fitExtent). [Example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5126418).

`fitExtent` takes two parameters:

1. *extent* is the top left and bottom right corner of the projection, represented by an array of two arrays – e.g. `[[0, 0], [width, height]]`.
2. *object* is a GeoJSON object.

If the top left corner of the projection is `[0, 0]`, you can use the convenience method `projection.fitSize()`, where you only pass the bottom right corner of the `extent`, represented by a single array of two items – e.g. `[width, height]`.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's a mix of both. According to the API, *projection*.center:

> sets the projection’s center to the specified location, a two-element array of longitude and latitude in degrees and returns the projection.

So, it's used to set the center of the map. Regarding *projection*.translate:

> If point is specified, sets the projection’s translation offset to the specified two-element array [x, y] and returns the projection. If point is not specified, returns the current translation offset which defaults to [480, 250]. The translation offset determines the pixel coordinates of the projection’s center. The default translation offset places ⟨0°,0°⟩ at the center of a 960×500 area.

As you can see, *projection*.translate depends on *projection*.center (*"the translation offset determines the pixel coordinates of the projection’s center"*). So, both values will determine how the map sits in its container

This is a demo showing the map of Japan (this code is not mine) in a smaller SVG, 500x500. In this one, we'll set the translate to the middle of the SVG:

```
.translate([width/2, height/2]);
```

Check the demo:

```js
var topoJsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1662536/topojson/japan.topo.json";

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    scale = 1;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
    .append("g").attr("id", "all-g");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([138, 38])
  .scale(1000)
  .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);
    
d3.json(topoJsonUrl, onLoadMap);

function onLoadMap (error, jpn) {
    var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
 var features = topojson.object(jpn, jpn.objects.japan);
  
  var mapJapan = features;
  

 d3.select("#all-g")
        .append("g").attr("id", "path-g").selectAll("path")
            .data(features.geometries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#f0f0f0")
            .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "path" + i})
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5/scale)
            .attr("d", path);

}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
```

And, in this one, to the left:

```
.translate([width/4, height/2]);
```

Check the demo:

```js
var topoJsonUrl = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1662536/topojson/japan.topo.json";

var width = 500,
    height = 500,
    scale = 1;

d3.select("body").append("svg")
 .attr("width", width)
 .attr("height", height)
    .append("g").attr("id", "all-g");

var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([138, 38])
  .scale(1000)
  .translate([width / 4, height / 2]);
    
d3.json(topoJsonUrl, onLoadMap);

function onLoadMap (error, jpn) {
    var path = d3.geo.path()
          .projection(projection);
 var features = topojson.object(jpn, jpn.objects.japan);
  
  var mapJapan = features;
  

 d3.select("#all-g")
        .append("g").attr("id", "path-g").selectAll("path")
            .data(features.geometries)
            .enter()
            .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#f0f0f0")
            .attr("id", function(d,i){ return "path" + i})
            .attr("stroke", "#999")
            .attr("stroke-width", 0.5/scale)
            .attr("d", path);

}
```

```css
path {
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/topojson.v0.min.js"></script>
```

In both cases, however, changing *projection*.center will move the map in its container.

Comment: So projection.center moves the map in [lat, long] space and projection.translate moves the map in projected [x, y] space?

Comment: Ok. So how do I make the projected map fill the parent container? Do I use d3.scale? And does d3.scale work in map space or in the projected plane?

Comment: These examples sadly don't work anymore because the Dropbox content they are based on is not available anymore. Better to use GitHub Gist / bl.ocks.org next time!